# Matching values from one csv file to another and replace entire column using pandas/python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, replace

Consider the following example:

I have a dataset of Movielens-

**u.item.csv**

```
ID|MOVIE NAME (YEAR)|REL.DATE|NULL|IMDB LINK|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|
1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
3|Four Rooms (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%20(1995)|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
```

Seperator used here is Pipe, which is still manageable.

**training_data.csv**

```
,user_id,movie_id,rating,unix_timestamp
0,1,1,5,874965758
1,1,2,3,876893171
2,1,3,4,878542960
```

Since I need to show the Movie names in "Training_data", instead of "movie id" I need to match every ID of **u.item.csv** with movie_id with **training_data.csv** and then replace it.

I'm using Python Pandas, and The training data was converted from Sframe to Dataframe to CSV. So that I could acquire the required change, which is yet unsuccessful. I can surely use some looping structure, but matching and replacing is real challenge I face.

P.s. I know Training data will be in sequence per user and will produce the exact output if replaced, but I need to learn this so that when I recommend movies I need MOVIE Names to displayed and not IDs.

I've already tried

1. [THIS (pandas-python-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple-columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426321/pandas-python-replace-multiple-values-in-multiple-columns)  - But can cost a lot of time when I have 100K values in Dataset
2. [THIS (pandas-replace-multiple-values-one-column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100130/pandas-replace-multiple-values-one-column)  - Matching values not explained
3. [THIS (pandas-replacing-column-values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888871/pandas-replacing-column-values)  - Manual entries are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
print (df1.set_index('ID')['MOVIE NAME (YEAR)'])
ID
1     Toy Story (1995)
2     GoldenEye (1995)
3    Four Rooms (1995)
Name: MOVIE NAME (YEAR), dtype: object

df2['movie_id'] = df2['movie_id'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['MOVIE NAME (YEAR)'])
print (df2)
   user_id           movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0        1   Toy Story (1995)       5       874965758
1        1   GoldenEye (1995)       3       876893171
2        1  Four Rooms (1995)       4       878542960
```

Or use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df2['movie_id'] = df2['movie_id'].replace(df1.set_index('ID')['MOVIE NAME (YEAR)'])
print (df2)
   user_id           movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0        1   Toy Story (1995)       5       874965758
1        1   GoldenEye (1995)       3       876893171
2        1  Four Rooms (1995)       4       878542960
```

Difference is if not match, `map` create `NaN` and replace let original value:

```
print (df2)
   user_id  movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0        1         1       5       874965758
1        1         2       3       876893171
2        1         5       4       878542960 <- 5 not match

df2['movie_id'] = df2['movie_id'].map(df1.set_index('ID')['MOVIE NAME (YEAR)'])
print (df2)
   user_id          movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0        1  Toy Story (1995)       5       874965758
1        1  GoldenEye (1995)       3       876893171
2        1               NaN       4       878542960
```

---

```
df2['movie_id'] = df2['movie_id'].replace(df1.set_index('ID')['MOVIE NAME (YEAR)'])
print (df2)
   user_id          movie_id  rating  unix_timestamp
0        1  Toy Story (1995)       5       874965758
1        1  GoldenEye (1995)       3       876893171
2        1                 5       4       878542960
```

Comment: Meanwhile I try this, can you pass on some helpful links to study map & set_index, other than manual. Something I can try out practically.

Comment: Sure, pandas docs is very good and there are also some nice explanation. For map check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html?highlight=map#applying-elementwise-functions) and for set index [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-an-index)

Comment: The code is more than better. I have learnt to replace, append and rename columns through it. Much greatful @jezrael