# Find string in one csv and replace with string in a different csv in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, bash, dataframe, csv

I have two csv files. `csv1` looks like this:

```
Title,glide gscore,IFDScore
235,-9.01,-1020.18
235,-8.759,-1020.01
235,-7.301,-1019.28
```

while `csv2` looks like this:

```
ID,smiles,number
28604361,NC(=O)CNC(=O)CC(c(cc1)cc(c12)OCO2)c3ccccc3,102
14492699,COc1cccc(c1OC)C(=O)N2CCCC(C2)CCC(=O)Nc3ccc(F)cc3C,235
16888863,COc1cc(ccc1O)CN2CCN(CC=C(C)C)C(C2)CCO,108
```

Both are much larger than what I show here. I need some way to match each value in the `Title` column of `csv1` to the corresponding value in the `number` column of `csv2`. When a match is found, I need the value in the `Title` column of `csv1` to be replaced with the corresponding value in the `ID` column of `csv2`. Thus I would want my desired output to be:

```
Title,glide gscore,IFDScore
14492699,-9.01,-1020.18
14492699,-8.759,-1020.01
14492699,-7.301,-1019.28
```

I am looking for a way to do it through pandas, bash or python.

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173627/matching-values-from-one-csv-file-to-another-and-replace-entire-column-using-pan) is close but gives me an ambiguous truth value of a DataFrame.
- I also tried `update` in pandas without luck.

I'm not pasting the exact code I've tried yet because it would be overwhelming to see faulty code in pandas, bash and python all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `map` it; then use `fillna` in case there were any "Titles" that did not have a matching "number":

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv('first_csv.csv')
csv2 = pd.read_csv('second_csv.csv')
csv1['Title'] = csv1['Title'].map(csv2.set_index('number')['ID']).fillna(csv1['Title']).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      Title  glide gscore  IFDScore
0  14492699        -9.010  -1020.18
1  14492699        -8.759  -1020.01
2  14492699        -7.301  -1019.28
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` module to load your dataframe, and then, using `merge` function, you can achieve what you are seeking for:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("df1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("df2.csv")

merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on="Title", right_on="number", how="right")
merged["Title"] = merged["ID"]
merged
```

##### Output

|  | Title | glide gscore | IFDScore | ID | smiles | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 28604361 | nan | nan | 28604361 | NC(=O)CNC(=O)CC(c(cc1)cc(c12)OCO2)c3ccccc3 | 102 |
| 1 | 14492699 | -9.01 | -1020.18 | 14492699 | COc1cccc(c1OC)C(=O)N2CCCC(C2)CCC(=O)Nc3ccc(F)cc3C | 235 |
| 2 | 14492699 | -8.759 | -1020.01 | 14492699 | COc1cccc(c1OC)C(=O)N2CCCC(C2)CCC(=O)Nc3ccc(F)cc3C | 235 |
| 3 | 14492699 | -7.301 | -1019.28 | 14492699 | COc1cccc(c1OC)C(=O)N2CCCC(C2)CCC(=O)Nc3ccc(F)cc3C | 235 |
| 4 | 16888863 | nan | nan | 16888863 | COc1cc(ccc1O)CN2CCN(CC=C(C)C)C(C2)CCO | 108 |

Note that the `Nan` values are due to unavailable values. If your dataframe covers these parts too, it won't result in `Nan`.

Comment: If you switch df1 for df2 when loading the csv files, and swap the `Title` in the merged file so it looks like `merged["number"] = merged["ID"]` and then use `merged.drop(columns=['smiles', 'number', 'Title'])` this would work

Comment: @ChristianSeitz Thanks for the comment, Christian. There is not much difference in changing the `number` or `Title` column. Both will work fine. And about the drop part, of course, dropping would make more precise, but since I was not sure whether it is of interest to you, I decided not to drop anything.